# Django API: Error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) and HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm currently working on a Django project and encountered some issues with the login functionality. I have a React component called **`LoginPage.js`** which sends a POST request to the Django API for the farmer and customer login. However, I'm receiving the following errors:

1. In the browser console, I see the error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)".
2. When I try to access the URL **`GET /api/farmer/login/`**, I receive the error "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed".

   API endpoint view shows error:

   ```
   HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
   Allow: POST, OPTIONS
   Content-Type: application/json
   Vary: Accept

   {
       "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
   }
   ```

React browser console error:

"POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/farmer/login/ 401 (Unauthorized)"

I have provided the relevant code snippets below for reference:

**LoginPage.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './css/LoginPage.css';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const handleRedirect = (userType) => {
    if (userType === 'farmer') {
      window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/create/';
    } else if (userType === 'customer') {
      window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/list/';
    }
  };
  

  const handleSubmit = (event, userType) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const data = {
      email_or_mobile: username,
      password: password
    };
  
    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${userType}/login/`, data)
      .then((response) => {
        const { message } = response.data;
        if (message === 'Invalid login credentials') {
          setErrors(['Invalid login credentials']);
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ user_type: userType }));
          handleRedirect(userType);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        setErrors(['An error occurred. Please try again.']);
      });
  };
  
  
  return (
    <div className="login-page">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
        />
        <h1>Login</h1>
      <div className="login-buttons">
        <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'farmer')}>
          Login as Farmer
        </button>
        <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'customer')}>
          Login as Customer
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
      {errors.map((error) => (
        <p key={error}>{error}</p>
      ))}
      <p>
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/registration">Sign Up</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Django **models.py:**

```
# Farmer model
class Farmer(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    aadhaar_card = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    stripe_connect_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

        
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = password



# Customer model
class Customer(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    aadhaar_card = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = password
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email_or_mobile = forms.CharField(label='Email or Mobile')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email_or_mobile = cleaned_data.get('email_or_mobile')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email_or_mobile and password:
            # Authenticate the user using email or mobile and password
            user = authenticate(email_or_mobile=email_or_mobile, password=password)
            if user is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid login credentials')
            cleaned_data['user'] = user
        return cleaned_data
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email_or_mobile = serializers.CharField(label='Email or Mobile')
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    def validate(self, attrs):
        form = UserLoginForm(data=attrs)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'), email_or_mobile=attrs['email_or_mobile'],
                                password=attrs['password'])
            if user is None:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid login credentials')
            attrs['user'] = user
            return attrs
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(form.errors)
```

**views.py:**

```
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class FarmerLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email_or_mobile = request.data.get('email_or_mobile')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        farmer = None

        # Check if email_or_mobile is a valid email
        if '@' in email_or_mobile:
            farmer = Farmer.objects.filter(email=email_or_mobile).first()

        # If not found, check if it is a valid mobile number
        if farmer is None:
            farmer = Farmer.objects.filter(phone_number=email_or_mobile).first()

        if farmer is not None:
            farmer_user = authenticate(request=request, email=farmer.email, password=password)
            if farmer_user is not None:
                login(request, farmer_user)
                return Response({'message': 'Login successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class CustomerLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):
        email_or_mobile = request.data.get('email_or_mobile')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        customer = None

        # Check if email_or_mobile is a valid email
        if '@' in email_or_mobile:
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(email=email_or_mobile).first()

        # If not found, check if it is a valid mobile number
        if customer is None:
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(phone_number=email_or_mobile).first()

        if customer is not None:
            customer_user = authenticate(request=request, email=customer.email, password=password)
            if customer_user is not None:
                login(request, customer_user)
                return Response({'message': 'Login successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response({'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

The error messages suggest that the server is responding with a 401 status code (Unauthorized) and that the GET method is not allowed for the **`/api/farmer/login/`** URL.

I have checked the code, and it seems that the login logic is correctly implemented. However, I'm unable to figure out why I'm encountering these errors.

Could anyone please help me understand why I'm getting the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" error in the browser console, as well as the "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed" error when accessing the **`GET /api/farmer/login/`** URL?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

React login component should fetch credential data from Django models for validation such as email or mobile number and password to login purpose.

I have tried to investigate the issue by checking the code implementation in both the **`LoginPage.js`** component and the Django views. I expected that when I enter valid login credentials for registered farmers or customers, the login should be successful, and I should be redirected to the appropriate component based on the user type. Additionally, I expected to see an error message displayed if the login credentials were invalid.

However, instead of the expected behaviour, I encountered two issues. First, when submitting the login form, I received the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" error in the browser console. Second, when trying to access the URL **`GET /api/farmer/login/`**, I received the "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed" error.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why these errors are occurring and how I can resolve them to achieve the expected login functionality. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your django code with postman or any other tool and its LOGIN api works or not? The error shows that your login is also not allowed without login.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar Can you please suggest to me the modification for these issues?